# Is there a formal name for the shortest (directed) line segment connecting two skew lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, terminology, physics

Is there a formal name for the shortest (directed) line segment connecting two skew lines? I don't believe the dimension of the space matters so long as it is greater than 2.  But I am specifically interested in the case of Euclidean 3-space.

I call this the *impact vector*, which I borrowed from the notion of an *impact parameter* used in astronomy to quantify the shortest distance between bodies. For example, how close an asteroid comes when passing Earth.  I call the associated directed line segment (with an arbitrarily designated tail) the *impact vector.*

Is there a mathematically proper term for this?

Comment: If you are talking about force, it is called "lever arm" or "moment arm"

Comment: The same term is sometimes used with angular velocity and angular momentum, so I guess lever arm is a viable candidate.

Comment: I’ve heard this line called the “join” of the two lines, or their “common normal”.